# Segmentize very long lines in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers

Is there a Segmentization method for lines in Openlayers?

My problem is when drawing a very long line in Openlayers it draws it as a straight line, although it should appear as a curve (because of the curvature of the earth)

See the attached figure (the figure is from SQLSever Management Studio), it's for the following line:

'LINESTRING(26.16867957625264 25.30479198505643, 126.3173281947216 25.30479198505643)'

In PostGIS there is ST_Segmentize that does exactly that, but I need to do that in the front-end.
[image: figrue]

Comment: What about using *arc.js* like in this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/flight-animation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [lineChunk function in Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/docs#lineChunk) which is compatible with OpenLayers